# Issues With Inheriting Entry Box Widget With Tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter

write a GUI in Tkinter using Python 2.11 using an OOP approach and trying to learn inheritance.  In the GUI below I have two entry widgets.  The first widget with the label "Enter Value - Does Not Return" uses the class EntryField which inherits from the Tkinter Entry Class.  When you input a value in this entry box the method setDesVol is called but the value in self.desV is not returned. If I try the other statement self.desV = self.parent.get() (which is commented out) gives an error that says MainWindow instance has no attribute get.

Now when I call the next entry widget assigned to the object entValue this works perfectly fine since it is contained in the MainWindow class and uses the method setValue and self.entValue.get() works as intended.

Does anyone have any ideas on what I am doing wrong in the EntryField class to get the value from the entry box.  My plan is to have more entry boxes in the final GUI and would like each entry box to have its own associated method such as setDesVol to keep the code cleaner and more manageable.  I have spent about 3 days trying to figure this out so any help is appreciated.  The code is attached below.  Thanks

```
import Tkinter as tk
import ttk
import tkMessageBox as mBox

class MainWindow(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent

        self.olFrame = tk.LabelFrame(text = 'Open Loop Frame', bg = 'red')
        self.olFrame.grid(column = 0, row = 0, sticky = 'w')
        self.voltLabel = tk.Label(self.olFrame,
                text = 'Enter Value - Does Not Return ',
                font = ("Times", 10), bg = 'red').grid(column = 0, row = 1)

        #entry box code that does not return anything
        self.entDesVolt = EntryField(self.olFrame,bg = 'red')
        self.entDesVolt.bind("<Return>", EntryField(self).setDesVol)
        self.entDesVolt.grid(column = 1, row = 1)

        #this entry box code works fine
        self.mezLabel = tk.Label(self.olFrame,
                text = 'Enter Another Value - works right ',
                font = ("Times", 10), bg = 'grey').grid(column = 0, row = 2)
        self.entValue = tk.Entry(self.olFrame, bg = 'grey')
        self.entValue.bind("<Return>", self.setValue)
        self.entValue.grid(column = 1, row = 2)

    def setValue(self, event):
        print self.entValue.get()
        print 10 + float(self.entValue.get())

class EntryField(tk.Entry):
    def __init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Entry.__init__(self, parent, *args, **kwargs)
        self.parent = parent
        print "self.parent in EntryField is type:  ", type(self.parent)

    def setDesVol(self,event):
        self.desV = EntryField(self).get()  #doesnt return anything in print statement
        #self.desV = self.parent.get()  #MainWindow instance has no attribute get
        #self.desV = tk.Entry(self).get()  #doesnt return anything in print statement
        print "self des V is:  ", self.desV

root = tk.Tk()
root.geometry('500x400')
root.title('Test GUI')
root.configure(background = "black")

a = MainWindow(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

In the `EntryField` class, in the `setDesVol` method, you use:

```
`self.desV = EntryField(self).get()`
```

So you create a new `EntryField` instance and call its `get` method which return `''` since entries are empty by default. To get the content of the current `EntryField`, just call the `get` method it inherited from `tk.Entry:

```
`self.desV = self.get()`
```

You have a similar problem in the `MainWindow` class when you do the bindings:

```
self.entDesVolt = EntryField(self.olFrame, bg='red')
self.entDesVolt.bind("<Return>", EntryField(self).setDesVol)
```

The second line creates an `EntryField` and binds its `setDesVol` method to the Return key presses in `self.entDesVolt`. Since this new `EntryField` is empty, any Return key press prints "self des V is:  ". To correct that, just directly bind the `setDesVol` method of `self.entDesVolt` to Return key presses:

```
self.entDesVolt = EntryField(self.olFrame, bg='red')
self.entDesVolt.bind("<Return>", self.entDesVolt.setDesVol)
```